# FileNotFoundError, OSError

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Please help to resolve the following issues.

I am trying to run the following codes in one cell of Juypter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook'])
import sympy as smp
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
from scipy.fft import fftfreq
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft, fft2, ifft2
```

BUT receive the following error messages:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\style\core.py:166, in use(style)
    165 try:
--> 166     style = _rc_params_in_file(style)
    167 except IOError as err:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:850, in _rc_params_in_file(fname, transform, fail_on_error)
    849 rc_temp = {}
--> 850 with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
    851     try:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py:135, in _GeneratorContextManager.__enter__(self)
    134 try:
--> 135     return next(self.gen)
    136 except StopIteration:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:827, in _open_file_or_url(fname)
    826 fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
--> 827 with open(fname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    828     yield f

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'science'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 4
      2 import scipy as sp
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook'])
      5 import sympy as smp
      6 from skimage import color

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\style\core.py:168, in use(style)
    166         style = _rc_params_in_file(style)
    167     except IOError as err:
--> 168         raise IOError(
    169             f"{style!r} is not a valid package style, path of style "
    170             f"file, URL of style file, or library style name (library "
    171             f"styles are listed in `style.available`)") from err
    172 filtered = {}
    173 for k in style:  # don't trigger RcParams.__getitem__('backend')

OSError: 'science' is not a valid package style, path of style file, URL of style file, or library style name (library styles are listed in `style.available`)
```

I used to run the codes and expect no error messages. But it seems that the error prompted after I ran the following code in one cell of Juypter notebook:

```
%pip install opencv-python
```

I am using Python 3.10.

Answer (score 2):

The case seems to be that `plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook'])` is an erroneous snippet of code.

In order to debug this error:

```
from matplotlib import style

print(plt.style.available)
```

This returns the following:

```
[‘Solarize_Light2’, ‘_classic_test_patch’, ‘bmh’, ‘classic’, ‘dark_background’, ‘fast’, ‘fivethirtyeight’, ‘ggplot’,’grayscale’,’seaborn’,’seaborn-bright’,’seaborn-colorblind’, ‘seaborn-dark’, ‘seaborn-dark-palette’, ‘seaborn-darkgrid’, ‘seaborn-deep’, ‘seaborn-muted’, ‘seaborn-notebook’, ‘seaborn-paper’, ‘seaborn-pastel’, ‘seaborn-poster’,’seaborn-talk’,’seaborn-ticks’,’seaborn-white’,’seaborn-whitegrid’,’tableau-colorblind10′]
```

You may be attempting to use packages which is not in the list of available packages for you to use. See below an example which uses correct references [Example code used below source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/style-plots-using-matplotlib/):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
from matplotlib import style
  
data = np.random.randn(50)
  
# consider this code which uses a package listed above.
plt.style.use('Solarize_Light2')
  
plt.plot(data)
  
plt.show()
```

Hope that helps